# Finding the point of intersection of $y=x^4$ and $x=y^2$.

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus

I need to find the point where $y=x^4$ and $x=y^2$ intersect. Since $x=y^2$ is not in $y$, I  need to square root both sides and get $\sqrt{x}$. Where I then set both of them equal to each other. $x^4=\sqrt{x}$.  I then  move $\sqrt{x}$
to the other side and get $x^4-\sqrt{x}=0$, but this is where I'm stuck. What I did is correct, right? and how would I find the point of intersection. I know one of them is $0$ since that is the origin of both functions.

Comment: Please read this [tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) on how to typeset mathematics on this site.

Answer (score 6):

Observe that the equations imply that $y=(y^2)^4=y^8$ or equivalently $y(y^7-1)=0$ so that $y=0$ or $y=1$. You can substitute to find $x$.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to other answers, you may find complex answers:

$$y=x^2$$

Substitute $x=y^4$ in.

$$y=(y^4)^2=y^8$$

$$y^8-y=0$$

$$y(y^7-1)=0$$

We have two solutions here:

$$y=0$$

Or

$$y^7-1=0$$

$$y^7=1$$

For complex solutions:

$$y=e^{\frac{2n}7\pi i},n=0,1,2,3,4,5,6$$

Plugging this back into the first equation, we have:

$$x=0,y=0$$

$$x=e^{\frac{n}7\pi i},y=e^{\frac{2n}7\pi i},n=0,1,2,3,4,5,6$$

Answer (score 0):

If you know that $x=y^2$ then just substitute x in the other equation. You get $y=y^8$:the solutions are $y=0$ and $y=1$. If $y=0$ you get $x=0$, if $y=1$ you get $x^2=1$ then $x=1$ or $x=-1$. The solutions are then the $(x,y)$ couples $(0,0),(1,1),(-1,1)$.

Answer (score 0):

From where you left off:

$x^4-\sqrt x=0$

Now factor out a $\sqrt x$

$\sqrt x (x^{\frac 72}-1)=0$

Now you can set

$\sqrt x = 0 \implies x =0$

$x^{\frac 72}-1=0 \implies x=1$

Now that you have your $x$ coordinates, you can plus them in in either equation and find the $y$ coordinates.

Comment: The problem with this is that x=y^2 does not only imply y = sqrt(x). The negative square root must also be considered (even though it does turn out to be useless).